# How to hide the year part in Html <input type="date"> calendar panel?

Tags: html, date, picker

Is there any way to hide the year part html   calendar panel, only show month and day part on the calendar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy answer, however you can use an alternative method to force the user to enter only month and date by using javascript.

```js
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
document.getElementById('date').setAttribute("min", year + "-01-01");
document.getElementById('date').setAttribute("max", year + "-12-31");
```

```html
<input type='date' id='date' />
```

The above code locks the year to current year, so the user will only be able to enter the month and the date.

---

If you still want to try the hard way, read these articles

- [jquery ui datepicker day/month only, not year selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10242886/2408342)
- [jQuery UI - Datepicker - Hide year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2698043/2408342)
- [Jquery datepicker - only day and month](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6799092/2408342)