# Can input type="date" select date in dd/mm format

Tags: html, reactjs, date

I am using HTML5 input type date.
By default input type="date" allows us to select date in dd/mm/yyyy format. I do not need year. Can I just get date in dd/mm format in my html form?
Note that I am using the form in render() method of ReactJS

Comment: If the year doesn't really matter to you, would it be acceptable for you to just show the current year, and then discard that information later?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the year part in Html <input type="date"> calendar panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680414/how-to-hide-the-year-part-in-html-input-type-date-calendar-panel)

Comment: Check out [**Is there any way to change input type=“date” format?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: @Ivar I tried putting the js code in componentDidMount(), but it is saving the setting the year as 2018(current year) in input type="date". I totally want to discard the year. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It will be fine if the year doesn't get displayed in the input type @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @PoojaChawla That is not possible for `input="date"` [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format). You'll have to find another way or try to find one of the many plugins that can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although a vanilla solution can include:

> The best way to deal with dates in forms in a cross-browser way at the
>   moment is to get the user to enter the day, month, and year in
>   separate controls ( elements being popular; see below for an
>   implementation), or to use a JavaScript library

what I do in my projects is to format dates with Cleave.js, in order to obtain a experience consistent through browsers and locales.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date