# Override dateFormat in existing jQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

Due to a very extensive plugin I do not want to mess in the core files to change the `dateFormat`. Calling the `dateFormat` in an alternative script is not bringing any changes, so I am looking for an alternative solution. This is my case:

Based on [this thread and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698043/jquery-ui-datepicker-hide-year#answer-8837293) I wanted to change the existing `dd-mm-yy` datepicker format into a `d MM` format. I had to hide the year with jQuery from the datepicker and the input field, by using the previous mentioned source:

```
jQuery('#user_birthday').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        inst.dpDiv.addClass('no-year-shown');
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst){
        inst.dpDiv.removeClass('no-year-shown');
    }
});
```

The years disappeared with this great solution, however the outcome is for example: `December\07` while the original displayed dateformat was `07-12-2018`. How do I override this, so it's `7 December` (EU format).

Answer (score 0):

How about using DateFormat Option:

$( "#user_birthday" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-MM" });

Comment: I meant in Addition to the css hiding. But if you tried it in combonation I said nothing.